# How do I kill a locked SSH session?

Tags: command-line, ssh

From time to time, SSH sessions to my servers just freeze up and then neither <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> nor <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> do anything.

How do I quit the session without just closing the Terminal it's in?

---

Clarification:

The session is locked as in, no keys are transmitted to the server. I'd like to shut it down gracefully, such that the user isn't logged in anymore.

I know I can kill the SSH client, but that will, in time, make the "`2 users`" info message I get from `uptime` meaningless. I'd like to know how many users are really logged in.

Comment: If you force quit your ssh session, the `bash` process on the remote server should be killed, causing you to log out. None of my servers keep me logged in after the SSH connections freeze (I'm using the default settings).

Answer (score 154, accepted):

To disconnect a locked-up ssh session, type<kbd>Enter</kbd> <kbd>~</kbd><kbd>.</kbd>

A full list of escape codes can be found in the [ssh manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh) or by typing <kbd>~</kbd><kbd>?</kbd>.

Comment: That seems perfect. I'll let you know when I get a chance to test it ;-)

Comment: It's very hard to type on the German keyboard, where the `~` is a dead key. But when I get it right, it works perfectly.

Comment: I needed the preceding `Enter` from @Jacob's answer

Comment: This does not work...

Comment: On the German keyboard, <kbd>option+n+.<kbd> will print <kbd>~<kbd> and immediately <kbd>.<kbd> again.

Comment: Has anyone identified when it is necessary to start with the Enter key before these two keys are pressed?

Comment: it's not hard I think: altgr ~ then .

Comment: In brazil you must press SPACE beetween ~ and .

Answer (score 66):

Type the following key sequence: <kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>~</kbd>, <kbd>.</kbd>. On US keyboards, the tilde (~) is <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>.

Comment: Nope, doesn't work.

Comment: Amazing! It works!

Comment: Kudos for pointing how to get the tilde.

Comment: Clearer than the accepted answer. Thanks!